# Swagger Codegen convert "format: time" to non String

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to customize the mappings between the OpenAPI Specification string formats

- time
- date
- date-time

to

- OffsetTime
- LocalDate
- Instant

respectively.

I'm currently using my own custom server generator that extends JavaJerseyServerCodegen, so I made this changes and everything worked fine

```
@Override
public void processOpts()
{
  super.processOpts();
  typeMapping.put("DateTime", "Instant");
  typeMapping.put("date", "LocalDate");

  importMapping.put("Instant", "java.time.Instant");
  importMapping.put("LocalDate", "java.time.LocalDate");
 ...
```

The problem is the time format, since the codegen doens't have this format defined by default so that I can "override" it.
Is it possible to do what I want? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of head banging, I tried a KISS approach and got the following solution:

```
@Override
public String getSwaggerType(final Property property)
{
  if ((property instanceof StringProperty) && ("time".equals(property.getFormat())))
  {
    return "OffsetTime";
  }
  else
  {
    return super.getSwaggerType(property);
  }
}
```

and now I can simply do the following

```
@Override
public void processOpts()
{
  super.processOpts();
  typeMapping.put("DateTime", "Instant");
  typeMapping.put("date", "LocalDate");
  typeMapping.put("time", "OffsetTime");

  importMapping.put("Instant", "java.time.Instant");
  importMapping.put("LocalDate", "java.time.LocalDate");
  importMapping.put("OffsetTime", "java.time.OffsetTime");
  ...
```